# MyBook.Close doesnt close hiding Excel windows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Start Workbook always open but always hidden where I put all my codes. It prompt an user form when it open and hide any excel on my computer.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Frm_Start.Show vbModeless
        Application.Visible = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End sub
```

Sometimes the codes open a new book (a report book), that have to be visible by the user. I just do:

```
    MyReportBook.Activate
```

and I can see the report (I didn't use application.visible = true)

When the user is done with this report book he can close it.

My first problem was that this action was closing the start book and I don't want this book to close. So I put those codes in the Before_Close of my start book (I check and when the user close the report book, the code start running in the start book!!):

```
    If MyUserFormThatMakeReport.visible = true then
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
            If wb.Name = "Report Book Name" Then
                wb.Save
                wb.Close
                Application.Quit
            End If
        Next wb
        Cancel = True
        Application.Visible = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End if
```

Thing is after it close, if I do application.visible = true:
- the workbook of the report book is still open
- the excel book is all grey
- the name of the report book is still on the top of the windows
- The start book is normal!!!

This is the first time I post on a forum, already 10 years I learn by myself with a big help of you and other forum. But this time I'm blocked, please help me.

Comment: Sorry this post start with "Hi guys", but it diseappear... so HY GUYS ;--))

Comment: Did you make sure that the statements `wb.Save : wb.Close` are executed? To check, you can place a breakpoint there. Also `Application.Quit` doesn't make sense here, and it looks like an indication that the bloc wasn't actually executed.

Comment: Thanks A.S.H for helping me.

Comment: Thanks A.S.H for helping me. I check again to be sure and wb.save / wb.close are running. the wb dim is the right book to save and close. Application.quit... well i see it in another answered question and I try it out but I don't know what it does. I delete it and the problem is exactly the same (it means you are right about it). The book is saved but i can't close his Excel windows...

Comment: Wow. Look like I find it. the application.visible have to be true before closing the workbook...

Answer (score 0):

If in the execution of your macro Application.visible went FALSE, make sure to turn it TRUE before closing a book.